# How to open only specific file extensions, e.g. .doc and not .docx?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I have been trying to open files in sub-directories using a .bat script with only the extension **.doc**. However, it also opening **.docx** files. I have tried using quotes and backslashes but to no avail.

```
for /r %%v in (*.doc) do start "" /b "%%~v"
```

How to open only ***.doc**, but not ***.docx**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /r %%v in (*.doc) do IF /i "%%~xv"==".doc" start "" /b "%%~v"
```

The problem arises because the mask matches the "shortname" *and* the "longname".